# init script does not return correct values based on actual condition

Tags: bash, shell, init

OK, I have fumbled with this long enough. I am working on an init script for an application and having a difficult time with the stop function. It always seems to match on my first condition and will never report correctly when the service is actually down.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

LOCKFILE=/var/lock/subsys/java
logger="/usr/bin/logger -t rc.local"
log_msg_start="Starting java Services:"
log_msg_stop="Stopping java Services:"
VAR=$(/usr/sbin/lsof -i :8080 | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $10}')
VAR2="(LISTEN)"
```

Above I expect the output of VAR to be "(LISTEN)" if the service is still running.

Code continued...

```
 stop(){
 echo -n "$log_msg_stop"
  cd /opt/java/bin/ ; ./java stop &>/dev/null &
  sleep 10
  rm -rf $LOCKFILE

  if [ "$VAR" == $VAR2 ]
  then echo "Still running, try again"

  elif [ "$VAR" != $VAR2 ]
  then echo "Service is stopped"
  fi

  echo
}
```

Seems simple enough right?

here is the debug output when I run the call.

```
+ LOCKFILE=/var/lock/subsys/java
+ logger='/usr/bin/logger -t rc.local'
+ log_msg_start='Starting java Services:'
+ log_msg_stop='Stopping java Services:'
++ /usr/sbin/lsof -i :8080
++ awk 'FNR == 2 {print $10}'
+ VAR='(LISTEN)'
+ VAR2='(LISTEN)'
+ case "$1" in
+ stop
+ echo -n 'Stopping java Services:'
Stopping java Services:+ cd /opt/java/bin/
+ sleep 10
+ ./java stop
+ rm -rf /var/lock/subsys/java
+ '[' '(LISTEN)' == '(LISTEN)' ']'
+ echo 'Still running, try again'
Still running, try again
+ echo

+ exit 0
```

Points of clarification:

1)this line:

```
cd /opt/java/bin/ ; ./java stop &>/dev/null &
```

is a chained command and is cd'ing to the folder then running ./java stop. I am doing it this way because it does not work any other way. FYI I am running it the same way for the start function and it works fine.

2) The concept of the stop function part of the script is to work with a buggy service that does not always shut down the first time. Hence the "still running, try again". Once I get this part of the script to detect the correct condition then I am going to work on a while loop to keep it running until it sees the correct condition.

3) I have also tried to output the status of the service to a text file and grep it for the contents to match on that. Doing it that way had no effect on behavior.

4) This service is ran using the format:

```
service java start
service java stop
service java status
```

FYI "java" is being substituted for the actual program I am working with.

Comment: `cd ..; ./java stop` is *not* chained. The `./java stop` will run even if `cd` fails, etc.

Comment: Also `./java stop &` runs it in the background so it may not have stopped by the time you check it. Also you are setting `$VAR` at the beginning of your script *before* you try to stop the service. That will **never** see the service having been stopped by your `stop` function.

Answer (score 0):

Also you are setting `$VAR` at the beginning of your script *before* you try to stop the service. That will **never** see the service having been stopped by your `stop` function. – Etan Reisner